# How do I add comma between each single quote in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlsx

I have a long string of words in an excel file

```
'MemberId''ProgramCode''Carrier''PolicyNumber''PolicyHolderName''EndorsementDate''DepartureDate''PolicyEffectiveDate''PolicyExpirationDate''NewRenew''StateCode''StreetAddress''City''ZipCode''CoverageType''PremiumPeriodBeginDate''PremiumPeriodEndDate'....
```

There are no spaces between these words so I cannot replace ' ' with ','. I just want my final list to look like the below with commas seperating each word in quotes-

```
'MemberId','ProgramCode','Carrier','PolicyNumber','PolicyHolderName','EndorsementDate','DepartureDate','PolicyEffectiveDate','PolicyExpirationDate','NewRenew'...
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your values are in A1 ...

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"''","','")
```